# ClipBucket file for preset 'normal' not found, failed to stat file in ffmpeg

Tags: linux, audio, video, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I am trying to fix my ffmpeg problems. When I upload any video it gives me an error that the file for preset 'normal' was not found, and it failed to stat the file. Any idea?

```
Started on 2013-09-10 20:50:45 - 2013 Sep 10

Checking File ....
File : /home/admin/clip/files/conversion_queue/13788318456eb9d.mkv
File Exists : Yes

Preparing file...
format : matroska,webm
duration : 137.71
size : 10177263
bitrate : 577
video_width : 554
video_height : 312
video_wh_ratio : 1.775641025641
video_codec : h264
video_rate : 24.99455377242
video_bitrate : 483
video_color : N/A
audio_codec : aac
audio_bitrate : 91
audio_rate : 44100
audio_channels : stereo
path : /home/admin/clip/files/conversion_queue/13788318456eb9d.mkv

Converting Video
Conversion Command : /usr/bin/ffmpeg -i /home/admin/clip/files/conversion_queue/13788318456eb9d.mkv  -f flv  -vcodec libx264 -vpre normal  -r 25 -s 554x312 -aspect  1.775641025641 -vf  pad=0:0:0:0:black -acodec libfaac -ab 128000  -ar 22050  /home/admin/clip/files/videos/13788318456eb9d.flv  2> /home/admin/clip/files/temp/13788318458b33a.tmp

Conversion Details

ffmpeg version 0.9.2, Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  >built on May 11 2013 13:27:19 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-52)
  >configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib --shlibdir=/usr/lib -->mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-shared --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-gpl --enable->version3 --enable-postproc --enable-avfilter --enable-pthreads --enable-x11grab --enable->vdpau --disable-avisynth --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable->libnut --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable->libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --extra->cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector -->param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m32 -march=i386 -mtune=generic -fasynchronous-unwind-tables' -->?>disable-stripping
 libavutil    51. 32. 0 / 51. 32. 0
  libavcodec   53. 42. 4 / 53. 42. 4
  libavformat  53. 24. 2 / 53. 24. 2
  libavdevice  53.  4. 0 / 53.  4. 0
  libavfilter   2. 53. 0 /  2. 53. 0
  libswscale    2.  1. 0 /  2.  1. 0
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0
Input #0, matroska,webm, from >'/home/admin/clip/files/conversion_queue/13788318456eb9d.mkv':
  Duration: 00:02:17.71, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 591 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 554x312 [SAR 1:1 DAR 277:156], 25 fps, >25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1: Audio: aac, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16 (default)
File for preset 'normal' not found
Failed to stat file /home/admin/clip/files/videos/13788318456eb9d.flv!
Failed to stat file /home/admin/clip/files/videos/13788318456eb9d.flv!

 Unknown file details - Unable to get output video details using FFMPEG 

Time Took : 0.0833 seconds
conversion_status : failed
```

Comment: Your ffmpeg build does not support the outdated `-vpre normal` option. Remove `-vpre normal` from the command.

Comment: there is no commend i am using script

Comment: You must modify the script that is creating the ffmpeg command, or make sure you are using the latest version of clipbucket. If you are, then ask the authors to consider updating the script to use recent ffmpeg syntax and not to use options that have been outdated and unsupported for more than two years.

Comment: i think i will change to the older ffmpeg because CB don't wrok with the new one

Comment: Next time please indent your code by 4 spaces, using the `{}` button in our editor, or by pressing `Ctrl-K` after selecting the text.